# Whats the proper way to upload multiple files using rails activestorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am trying to upload multiple 'supporting photos' files to my item model.

The supporting photos file has a has_many_attached association because there are to be multiple files uploaded.

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
   

    has_one_attached :cover_photo do |attachable|
        attachable.variant :medium, resize_to_limit:[300,300]
        attachable.variant :large, resize_to_limit:[1200,1000]
    end

    has_many_attached :supporting_photos do |attachable|
        attachable.variant :medium, resize_to_limit:[300,300]
        attachable.variant :large, resize_to_limit:[1200,1000]
    end
```

In the form the user is meant to fill, I have multiple divs with the file_field tag so the user can attach multpile 'supporting photos'

**items/new.html.erb**

```
  <div class="mt-2 flex justify-center rounded-lg border border-dashed border-gray-900/25 px-6 py-10">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      
                      <div class="mt-4 flex text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">
                      
                       <%= form.file_field :supporting_photos, direct_upload:true %>
                   
                      </div>
                       <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-600">or drag and drop</p>
                      <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-600">PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div  class="sm:col-span-2">
                
                  <div class="mt-2 flex justify-center rounded-lg border border-dashed border-gray-900/25 px-6 py-10">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      
                      <div class="mt-4 flex text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">
                
                      <%= form.file_field :supporting_photos, direct_upload:true %>
                   
                      </div>
                       <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-600">or drag and drop</p>
                      <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-600">PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div  class="sm:col-span-2">
                 
                  <div class="mt-2 flex justify-center rounded-lg border border-dashed border-gray-900/25 px-6 py-10">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      
                      <div class="mt-4 flex text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">
                
                        <%= form.file_field :supporting_photos, direct_upload:true %>
                   
                      </div>
                       <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-600">or drag and drop</p>
                      <p class="text-xs leading-5 text-gray-600">PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Finally here is my items controller, when I looked up how to do this, this was the solution I found but it gives me an error `Unpermitted parameter: :supporting_photos. Context: { controller: ItemsController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch...'` in my terminal console and also `undefined method each' for #<actiondispatch` in the browser when i load the form

**Does anyone know the proper way to do this? Please and thank you**

```
def new
    # @item = item.new
    @item = current_user.items.build
  end

  def create
    # @item = item.new(item_params)
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params.except(:supporting_photos))
    supporting_photos = params[:item][:supporting_photos]


    if supporting_photos
      supporting_photos.each do |supporting_photo|
        @item.supporting_photos.attach(supporting_photo)
      end
    end
    
    if @item.save
      
      redirect_to sell_sale_path
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


  private
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :brand, :colour, :condition, :department, :category, :price, :is_sold, :cover_photo, :description, supporting_photos: [])
    end
```

I would also like multiple file fields because I want to make it more intuitive for the user
This is what im going for

[image]

As opposed to this[image]

Comment: You do not need multiple inputs. Just use a one with `<%= form.file_field :supporting_photos, direct_upload: true, multiple: :true  %>` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

Answer (score 1):

No need for multiple file fields. Just one with `multiple: true` attribute

Also note that you need to wrap this param with `:item` key to permit it. Basically it's possible to use `form_with` with `:model` key for this purpose:

```
<%#= app/views/items/new.html.erb %>

<%= render "form", item: @item %>
```

```
<%#= app/views/items/_form.html.erb %>

<%= form_with(model: item) do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :supporting_photos, direct_upload: true, multiple: true %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But if you need ***to keep existing photos when update*** the item and reuse this form partial, you may need add multiple hidden fields:

```
<% item.supporting_photos.each do |sp| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :supporting_photos, multiple: true, value: sp.signed_id %>
<% end %>
```

On backend side you don't need explicitly attach photos (especially before saving) or iterate through params, just enough:

```rb
# app/controllers/items_controller.rb

def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)

  if @item.save
    redirect_to item_url(@item)
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private

def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(supporting_photos: [])
end
```

Comment: The reason I want multiple file fields is that I want to make it more intuitive for the user to attach each photo to each file field. If i use multiple:true it only gives me one file field. I just edited the original question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Looks less intuitive for me. Anyway you can upload and attach as answer describes even with multiple fields